# How do we know from trig functions the length of a line segment? (like how we know sin$\theta = \sqrt2/2$ means length $1$)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, multiple-integral

Sorry for the badly worded title, my trigonometry  knowledge is clearly lacking foundation.

I'm wondering about this because I'm learning how to evaluate double integrals in polar coordinates. How do we know what this integral: $$\int^\sqrt2_0 \int^{4-y^2}_y dxdy $$

would become in polar coordinates?

**TLDR**: 
What would the answer be if the upper limit on the original outer integral was $5$ instead of  $\sqrt2$?

Detailed thoughts:

It's easy to see that the limits on the inner integral trace out an angle of $\pi/4$, so I have the limits one of the new integrals (the one with respect to $\theta$): the limits are $0$ to $\pi /4$.

But how do I figure out the limits for the radius $r$? In this case I can see that the upper limit on the $y$ integral is $\sqrt2$. If I think of $y$ as being $r$sin$\theta$, then I see that $\sqrt2 / r= $sin$\theta$.

And luckily we know $r=2$ from the upper limit on the $x$ integral, so we see that sin$\theta = \sqrt2/2$ and can conclude that the limits on the outer integral should be $0$ to $1$, giving us our new double integral in polar coordinates:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi/4}r \ d\theta \ dr$$

But what if the upper limits on the original outer integral was, for example, $5$ instead of  $\sqrt2$?

Comment: Your integration domain is very irregular. It in fact makes not much geomtric sense as the curves $\;x=y,\,x=4-y^2\;$ don't intersect at $\;y=\sqrt2\;$ , so the domain's interpretation is not very clear...

Comment: @DonAntonio Personally I sketched the lines out. Indeed, they intersect at $0$, not at $\sqrt2$. This question is explicitly asking for a conversion to polar coordinates, so maybe it's a given that trying to think about this without considering polar coordinates is confusing? When you graph the lines you see that the region is a "slice" of a circle. In any case, I realize my answer was wrong...but still not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see a slice of any circle: $\;x\;$ is ranging between the straight line  $\;x=y\;$ and the **parabola** $\;x=4-y^2\;$ . Now, if the upper inner limit was $\;\sqrt{4-y^2}\;$ then there would certainly be a circle there...but not as it is!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are not accurate.

The two  integrals $$\int^\sqrt2_0 \int^{4-y^2}_y dxdy$$ and $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi/4}r \ d\theta \ dr$$

are not the same.

While your $\theta = \pi/4 $ is correct the boundary function $x=4-y^2$ is totally ignored in your calculations.

You need to convert the boundary function into polar form of $r=f(\theta)$ before changing your integralto polar form. coordinvhan

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the functions on the upper and lower limits of the integrals should be made into the form $r=f(\theta)$? Does that mean I should simply make substitutions of $y=r$sin$\theta$ and $x=r$cos$\theta$ for all functions? That seems like it'd put be in a more problematic spot than now. Apologies for being slow, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @JamesRonald  Yes,  you have to have your upper limit of $1$ replaced with  some $f(\theta)$ as you  have indicated in the above comment and that is not going to be an easy task. Also the outer integral should be  in term of $\theta$